# C# Login to garmin connect - new auth scheme

Tags: c#, webclient, garmin

Recently Garmin Connect changed their login procedure and I am trying to find information on how to do this in c#.

I found some basics on how to do this but it isn't working:

I took a look at the new login process. Garmin implemented a single sign-on approach using the so-called "GAuth widget".
You should be able to login as follows.

1) Get the GAuth widget by sending a HTTP GET request to e.g.
https://sso.garmin.com/sso/login?ser...edWidget=false

2) Parse the received HMTL code for "flowExecutionKey", e.g. "e1s1" in
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">    
<!-- flowExecutionKey: [e1s1] -->
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">    
<head> 
[...]
```

3) Post your login credentials by sending a HTTP POST request to the URL given in 1) with content:
        Code:

```
    _eventId=submit
    displayNameRequired=false
    embed=true
    lt=<YourFlowExecutionKey>
    password=<YourPassword>
    username=<YourUserName>
```

4) Parse the received HTML code for "response_url", e.g.Code:

```
[...]

    var redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl = 'http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login';
    var consumeServiceTicket = 'false';
    var service_url  = 'http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login';
    var parent_url   = 'http://connect.garmin.com/de-DE/signin';
    var response_url = 'http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login?ticket=ST-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-cas';
    var logintoken   = '';
    var social_uid   = '';

[...]
```

5) Login to garmin connect by sending a HTTP HEAD request to the response url. The "service ticket" (part starting with "ST-") proves your successful login via GAuth widget.

```
 **********************************************************************************************
```

This is the code I have so far but it never returns response_url in step 3. What am I missing?

```
        var url = "https://sso.garmin.com/sso/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&webhost=olaxpw-connect07.garmin.com&source=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fus-EN%2Fsignin&redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&redirectAfterAccountCreationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fpost-auth%2Flogin&gauthHost=https%3A%2F%2Fsso.garmin.com%2Fsso&locale=en&id=gauth-widget&cssUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.garmincdn.com%2Fcom.garmin.connect%2Fui%2Fsrc-css%2Fgauth-custom.css&clientId=GarminConnect&rememberMeShown=true&rememberMeChecked=false&createAccountShown=true&openCreateAccount=false&usernameShown=true&displayNameShown=false&consumeServiceTicket=false&initialFocus=true&embedWidget=false#";

    // Step 1
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    var result = wc.DownloadString(url);
    string[] splt1 = Regex.Split(result, "<!-- flowExecutionKey: ");
    string[] splt2 = Regex.Split(splt1[1], "] -->");
    var flowExecutionKey = splt2[0].Replace("[", "");

    // Step 2
    var formParams = new NameValueCollection();
    formParams.Add("_eventId", "submit");
    formParams.Add("displayNameRequired", "false");
    formParams.Add("embed", "true");
    formParams.Add("lt", flowExecutionKey);
    formParams.Add("password", "password");
    formParams.Add("username", "username");
    formParams.Add("service", "http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login");
    formParams.Add("redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl", "http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login");
    formParams.Add("redirectAfterAccountCreationUrl", "http://connect.garmin.com/post-auth/login");
    formParams.Add("webhost", "olaxpw-connect00.garmin.com");
    formParams.Add("clientId", "GarminConnect");
    formParams.Add("gauthHost", "https://sso.garmin.com/sso");
    formParams.Add("rememberMeShown", "true");
    formParams.Add("rememberMeChecked", "false");
    formParams.Add("consumeServiceTicket", "false");
    formParams.Add("id", "gauth-widget");
    formParams.Add("embedWidget", "false");
    formParams.Add("cssUrl", "https://static.garmincdn.com/com.garmin.connect/ui/src-css/gauth-custom.css");
    formParams.Add("source", "http://connect.garmin.com/en-US/signin");
    formParams.Add("createAccountShown", "true");
    formParams.Add("openCreateAccount", "false");
    formParams.Add("usernameShown", "true");
    formParams.Add("displayNameShown", "false");
    formParams.Add("initialFocus", "true");
    formParams.Add("locale", "en");
    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
    var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", formParams);
    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!
Ron